# How to compress files in Windows in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, compression

I can compress files or folders in Windows from GUI by right clicking and selecting "Send to .. Compressed (zip) file..".

Is it possible to do same in batch file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have very good experience using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).  It's open source and does an outstanding job of compression.  Lots of formats and strong encryption if you need it.  It has both GUI and command line versions.

Comment: +1, LZMA2 gives the best compression (on average, for general files) available right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be to head over to [7Zip.org](http://7zip.org), go to the download section and get the '7-Zip Command Line Version'. It supports most compression formats, is easy to use and free!
A command line example to compress a bunch of files with the bak extension to ZIP format would be:

```
7za a -tzip tinybak.zip *.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use compress.exe which is built into windows, but [WinRar](http://rarlabs.com/) is free and has command line based tools which I would recommend.

Comment: compress.exe only supports NTFS file systems and I believe it is a separate download (comes with the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit etc)

Comment: WinRar is not free. As of today it's $29/license with lower prices for volume purchases. http://www.rarlab.com/shop2rarlab.php?prod=winrar